# Add label to metadata

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I've started to use [kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/) to update the yaml files. 
I'm trying to add labels to `Deployment` object. `commonLabels` seems pretty good but it applies the label to `selector` as well (which I don't want)

Is there a way to add new label only to `metadata.labels` or `spec.template.metadata.labels`?

here's a sample `deployment` object :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    service: servieName
    owner: ownerName
  name: myName
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
         app: servieName
         owner: ownerName
         <newLableHere>: <newValueHere>
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to define a patch for that object specifically.